# How to make a dynamic bot command in discord?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I usually make a new bot command with the following lines of code:

```
private void SayHi()
{
    commands.CreateCommand("sayhi").Do(async (e) => {
            await e.Channel.SendMessage("Hi");
    });
}
```

Then the user in a channel can type `"!sayhi"` and it'll print out `"Hi"`. What I am trying to do using the `discord.net` package in `C#` is to make a dynamic command. So that the user can enter something like this: `!sayhi x` where `x` is whatever string the user chooses to use. And I will hopefully be able to output something like:

```
commands.CreateCommand("sayhi" + x).Do(async (e) => {
        await e.Channel.SendMessage("Hi" + x);
});
```

with the output in discord looking like: `"Hi x"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation. You would use the Parameter method

http://rtd.discord.foxbot.me/en/legacy/features/commands.html#example-simple

```
commands.CreateCommand("sayhi" + x)
                    .Parameter("Target", ParameterType.Required)
                    .Do(async (e) =>
                    {
                        await e.Channel.SendMessage("Hi" + e.GetArg("Target"));
                    });
```